# label attribute onclick function fired twice

Tags: javascript, html

I use onclick attribute in label tag when i put input tag with type checkbox inside  label it fire twice but once i changed the type to radio it works fine.

Here is my code

```js
function checkUncheck(el) {
  var input = $(el).find("input");
  console.log(input);
  alert("TESt");
  // console.log("input:", input);
  // console.log('$(input).parent("div").hasClass("opacity")', $(input).closest("div.config-box").hasClass("opacity"));

  var isClickable = $(input).closest("div.config-box").hasClass("opacity");

  if (isClickable != true) {
    if (input.attr("type") == "radio") {
      $(el).closest(".form-group").find("input[name='" + input.attr("name") + "']").closest(".img-check").removeClass("check").find('input').prop('checked', false);
      $(el).addClass('check').find('input').prop('checked', true).change();
    } else {
      if ($(el).hasClass("check")) {
        $(el).removeClass("check").find("input").prop("checked", false);
      } else {
        // alert("TEST");
        // el.classList.add("check");
        $(el).addClass("check").find("input").prop("checked", true);
        console.log($(el));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="img-check" onclick="checkUncheck(this)">
 <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://www.fujifilm.com.my/Products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG'); width: 20%;height: 200px;background-position: center;background-size: cover;"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chassis" value="valasdfas1" style="visibility:hidden" class="hidden" autocomplete="off">
</label>
```

Please see the example code here https://codepen.io/abdulqadir88/pen/WKjdEj

Comment: Changed your code to a snippet. Seems to work fine.

Comment: Please check the updated code where label has a div which contain background image and check box is hidden when click on image it alert twice in my local system

Comment: Connect the label to the ckeckbox using the `for` attribute, and then handle whatever you need to handle via the `change` event occurring on the checkbox.

Comment: Y down voting is there ?

Comment: @ CBroe That worked thanks Please post the answer i will accept

Comment: @CBroe Just out of curiosity. Could you please explain why the event is fired twice when the for attribute is not set?

Comment: @MarkBaijens didn’t check the example in detail, but probably the usual bubbling effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code Just added for attribute in the label and connected it with chassis That did the trick.

```js
function checkUncheck(el) {
  var input = $(el).find("input");
  console.log(input);
  alert("TESt");
  // console.log("input:", input);
  // console.log('$(input).parent("div").hasClass("opacity")', $(input).closest("div.config-box").hasClass("opacity"));

  var isClickable = $(input).closest("div.config-box").hasClass("opacity");

  if (isClickable != true) {
    if (input.attr("type") == "radio") {
      $(el).closest(".form-group").find("input[name='" + input.attr("name") + "']").closest(".img-check").removeClass("check").find('input').prop('checked', false);
      $(el).addClass('check').find('input').prop('checked', true).change();
    } else {
      if ($(el).hasClass("check")) {
        $(el).removeClass("check").find("input").prop("checked", false);
      } else {
        // alert("TEST");
        // el.classList.add("check");
        $(el).addClass("check").find("input").prop("checked", true);
        console.log($(el));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="img-check" for="chassis" onclick="checkUncheck(this)">
 <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://www.fujifilm.com.my/Products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG'); width: 20%;height: 200px;background-position: center;background-size: cover;"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chassis" value="valasdfas1" style="visibility:hidden" class="hidden" autocomplete="off">
</label>
```

Here is the working solution https://codepen.io/abdulqadir88/pen/QBvaYQ

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use type checkbox i whould prefer to add onclick event to the input element. Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chassis" value="valasdfas1" style="visibility:hidden" class="hidden" autocomplete="off" onclick="checkUncheck(this)">
```

But if you dont need checkbox input type yu can use hidden type like this:

```
 <label class="img-check" onclick="checkUncheck(this)">
     <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://www.fujifilm.com.my/Products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG'); width: 20%;height: 200px;background-position: center;background-size: cover;"></div>
     <input type="hidden" name="chassis" value="valasdfas1"  class="hidden" autocomplete="off" >
 </label>
```

You can find both solution here:
https://codepen.io/kovtib/pen/VBbrgq?editors=1111